# xcode 5 additional viewcontroller files

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

newbie to mobile app development in general and attempting to build a functioning prototype for a class project. Been searching for a solution that fits my situation without much luck. The only view controller file I have in my project is a FormViewController.h file. I'm attempting to add a basic login screen and a background to my pages but I can't figure out if I need to add viewcontroller.h/viewcontroller.m files to put code into or if I'm overlooking something even simpler? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add another view controller, you'll need to add a set of `.h`/`.m` files to your project. To create new files for a view controller, do this:

**File > New > File...**

---

[image: Step 1]

**Select Objective-C class**

---

[image: Step 2]

**Type in the name of the view controller you want to create and select `UIViewController` as its subclass.**

---

[image: Step 3]

**If you're using XIB files, you can click the checkbox to create another XIB file. If you're using storyboards, just drag another `UIViewController` into the storyboard and change its class.**

---

[image: Step 4]

Comment: Thanks! glad to know I wasn't missing anything by not having the files originally!